# Adding rows to Power BI datasets with API

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need to create a new dataset with a table as well as adding rows to that table using [Microsoft.PowerBI.Api](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerBI.Api/) framework. I'm looking for some c# code samples on how it could be done.

```
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(_authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
{
    ????
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 approaches, as described in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data-add-rows

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt203561.aspx

1. Using Power BI C# library `Microsoft.PowerBI.API`:

```c#
using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2;

...

var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(_authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
{
  string data = @"{  ""rows"":  
                                [
                                    { ""id"": 1, ""name"": ""Tom""},                                
                                    { ""id"": 2, ""name"": ""Jerry""}
                                ]
                            }";
  var dataJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(data.ToString());

  client.Datasets.PostRowsInGroup(groupId, datasetId, tableName, datajson);
}
```

2. Using HTTP directly, via PowerBI REST APIs:

```c#
private static void AddRows(string datasetId, string tableName)
        {
            string powerBIApiAddRowsUrl = String.Format("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{0}/tables/{1}/rows", datasetId, tableName);

            //POST web request to add rows.
            //To add rows to a dataset in a group, use the Groups uri: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{group_id}/datasets/{dataset_id}/tables/{table_name}/rows
            //Change request method to "POST"
            HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(powerBIApiAddRowsUrl) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            //Add token to the request header
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

            //JSON content for product row
            string rowsJson = "{\"rows\":" +
                "[{\"ProductID\":1,\"Name\":\"Adjustable Race\",\"Category\":\"Components\",\"IsCompete\":true,\"ManufacturedOn\":\"07/30/2014\"}," +
                "{\"ProductID\":2,\"Name\":\"LL Crankarm\",\"Category\":\"Components\",\"IsCompete\":true,\"ManufacturedOn\":\"07/30/2014\"}," +
                "{\"ProductID\":3,\"Name\":\"HL Mountain Frame - Silver\",\"Category\":\"Bikes\",\"IsCompete\":true,\"ManufacturedOn\":\"07/30/2014\"}]}";

            //POST web request
            byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rowsJson);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            //Write JSON byte[] into a Stream
            using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Console.WriteLine("Rows Added");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```